# Double superscript error in fractions

Tags: errors, superscripts

I'm basically new to LaTex and still learning, and while I'm trying to write this fraction:

```
$\frac{x}{sin({b_{2}})} = \frac{{A_{b}}{B_{a}}}{sin(C’’)}$
```

I get error: double superscript. I tried putting brackets in diffrent combinations but so far none have worked. Any ideas how can I make it work?

Edit:
When I put into a separate file, like that:

```
    \documentclass[b5paper,11pt,twoside,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
$\frac{x}{\sin{b_2}} = \frac{{A_b}{B_a}}{\sin{C’’}}$ \\
\end{document}
```

it works fine. But in the file I still get an error:

```
! Double superscript.
<recently read> ^
l.225 ...{b_2}} = \frac{{A_b}{B_a}}{\sin{C’’}}
\)
I treat `x^1^2' essentially like `x^1{}^2'.
```

And I should add the error appears as if it was in next line to the one with problematic code.

Edit 2:
I repaired it. Apparently I used a fancy version of ' when I was pasting part of my code form source. After putting a normal '' there everything was fine.

Comment: I don't get an error.  Please turn this into a minimal working example (document class and begin/end document).  Also, the error code (mysterious though it may be) is useful information.  Please copy and paste it.  (And you generally shouldn't put `{}` around things unless they need it: `sin({b_{2}})` should be `\sin(b_2)`.)

Comment: I too am not getting any errors. As a side note use ``\sin`` instead of sin.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal example doesn't show errors, but no prime appears either.

In the second example, you have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and you get the error, together with

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textquoteright invalid in math mode
```

You have to use an *undirected* quote for getting a prime in math mode.

```
$\frac{x}{\sin b_2} = \frac{A_bB_a}{\sin C''}$
```

By the way, you don't need braces after `\sin`, nor around `A_b` and `B_b`.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out maybe a few seconds before I saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's your input that is causing the problem; separate the "text right quote `’`" with `{}` in order to avoid the error. However, there are other options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$A''$ % <----- preferred

$B’{}’$

$C^{\prime\prime}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exatcly it (though I figured it ou seconds before I saw you comment)

Comment: `’{}’` is wrong anyway, because it produces warnings and the wrong spacing; also `^\prime{}^\prime` is likewise wrong and should be `^{\prime\prime}`.