# Compiling bibliography file

Tags: texmaker, warnings

I have a question that is more curiosity than any real need to fix anything.

I have a line in my document that reads:

```
'Where $\wedge$ is the wedge product, and $r$ and $r'$ are the ...'
```

Which comes out fine as:

> Where ^ is the wedge product, r and r' are the ...

However TexMaker gives the warning:

> Command \textquoteright invalid in math mode.

I assume this refers to the $\wedge$, but \wedge without the math qualifiers does not work, so what is TexMaker looking for here?

Also, again just curiosity, on a completely blank line I get the warning (badbox):

> Line 226 Overfull \hbox in paragraph at lines 226--226

from:

```
225 \printbibliography
226
227 \end{document}
```

Comment: You say you assume that the $\wedge$ is the problem, you can easily test this by simply removing/commenting it :)

Comment: @Foitn Of course, you're right :-). I shouldn't have said I assume \$wedge$ is the problem, I know it is, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure it is the `\wedge` and not the `'` in `$r'$`? I'm just guessing here because I don't know your document set-up. Do you by chance have a `'` anywhere in your bibliography?

Comment: Another guess. Do you by any chance have a `’` instead of a `'` for a prime in math mode somewhere? (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345309/35864)

Comment: moewe yes! That fixed one of the warnings. Now I'm confused as to why removing wedge removed the warning on that line, but at least its gone :-). Now, the overfull \hbox!

Comment: If there an overfull/underfull box appears in the bibliography created by `\printbibliography` it will be marked as appearing in the line after the `\printbibliography` command. Normally the warning message contains the content of the overfull/underfull box so that you should be able to identify the problematic bib entry with a bit of detective work.